# I cant make the indexOf method to work based on an integer

Tags: java, methods, indexof

I have to write a program that where one inputs a String and the program returns the backwards version of that String. I am using an indexOf method to count the letters in it and then invert it. The code I'm using is:

**MAIN CLASS**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter word");
    String word = in.nextLine;
    word = in.nextLine;
    String separate[];
    Reverse rev = new Reverse();
    rev.returnrev(word, separate);
    rev.print(separate);
  }
}
```

**METHOD CLASS**

```
public class Reverse{
  public String returnrev(String word, String separate[]){
    int len = word.length();
    separate = new String[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
      separate[i] = word.indexOf(len-i, len-i+1);
    };
  }
  public String print(String separate[]){
    int slen = separate.length;
    for(int i=0;i<slen;i++){
    System.out.print(separate[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: CharAt to get the char at i position in the string, with a reversed loop

Comment: str.indexOf() returns an `int`, you are storing it in a string. Also, indexOf() returns the position of a string or character in a string. For your purpose, charAt() would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Read the API for the `String.indexOf(...)` method. It does not do what you think it does. The `indexOf(...)` method returns an "int" value, not a String value.

I think you want to use the `String.substring(...)` method (based on your existing logic). It does return a String value.